# 'int' object is not iterable, map() passing trough a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So lets I have this list;

`yy=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

and I want a map() to go through the list using the np.std() this,

`np. std(1,2,3), std(2,3,4), std(3,4,5) .... std(8,9,10)`

so I thought of doing something like this,

```
import numpy as np
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n = 3
x = map(lambda w, n: np.std(y[x-n:x]), range(n,len(y)), n)
print(list(x))
```

But I get this error 'int' object is not iterable, how do I fix this?

Comment: You're passing `map` 3 arguments, and the third is an `int`.  What do you expect that to do?  This is probably why Guido wanted to eliminate `map` entirely, preferring generators and list comprehensions instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing too many iterables to `map`. You just need to pass the start index for each piece of the list that you want to `np.std()`

```
import numpy as np
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n = 3
x = map(lambda i: np.std(y[i:i+n]), range(len(y) - n)) # pass only the start index for each iteration
print(list(x))
```

Result:

```
[0.816496580927726, 0.816496580927726, 0.816496580927726, 0.816496580927726, 0.816496580927726, 0.816496580927726, 0.816496580927726]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I see what you were trying to do.  You expected the single value of `n` to be passed each time into your lambda function.  But that's not how `map` works, it expects all its arguments to be iterables.

You had another problem, you are passing `w` into your lambda function but trying to use it as `x`.

Here's the version of your code with those two problems fixed:

```
x = map(lambda w, n: np.std(y[w-n:w]), range(n,len(y)), [n]*len(y))
```

You can simplify it by realizing that you don't need to pass `n` into the lambda function at all, it's already defined in the scope where you're creating the function.

```
x = map(lambda w: np.std(y[w-n:w]), range(n,len(y)))
```

Finally you can use a generator expression instead of `map`.

```
x = (np.std(y[w-n:w]) for w in range(n,len(y)))
```